# How do I modify vertex groups weights with Geometry Nodes in Blender 3.0?

Tags: vertex-groups, procedural, geometry-nodes

I am trying to modify the weights of a vertex group in Blender 3.0 in Geometry nodes but I am not able to do it properly. I can't create weights like values instead of boolean type values.

As you can see in the image, the values seem to come out as 0 or 1
therefor the coverage in the second geonodes is not gradual.

[image]

The blend file
https://pasteall.org/blend/882db18f1e4b4030959a2ff85702da61

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made nearly everything right.

You just have to adapt two things:

change your selection output type from boolean to float (in first gn)

[image]

change your selection input type from boolean to float (in second gn)

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, that seemed to get alot of things going in my scene but I still cant get that nice transition :( Blend file https://pasteall.org/blend/f454eca7fa03476791fe015e14a402cf    Screen https://pasteall.org/pic/f68f34cba51b41399ccdbd8dfb40a429

Comment: in your file, just change distance min to 0 and distance max to 26 and you will get [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYXPi.png. But if you have further/other questions, please open another question, because i answered your question already. And you should ask only one question...

Answer (score 1):

In 3.0 RC, vertex groups are modified like you're showing: you plug a noodle into an empty output, and in your modifier stack, you designate one of your vertex groups as this output:

[image]

The nearer mesh shows our "base" orientation; we assign it to "Group" via geo nodes; and then we displace on the basis of Group, demonstrating this working.  It is not Boolean, but gradual, as you want.

Something else is responsible for you not getting the output you expect.  You didn't ask about that, but if you do in a future question, we would need more information to answer it, preferably an entire file.  It may be because you didn't designate Group as an input to your second geo nodes modifier (can't see because it's collapsed.)  You may be seeing strange behavior because your vertices all have a very large or small (maybe negative) Y location, relative to the origin of their object, and those values get clamped by your color ramp to 1 or 0 respectively.  Or, there may be some other reason.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I added the .blend file tom my post.